# meaning of to in the given sentence

Tags: usage

In the following sentence

> Last week the Supreme Court issued a notice to the Centre, the National Human Rights Commission (NHRC) and the State governments **to a plea** seeking the implementation of its July 2018 judgment laying down several preventive, remedial and punitive measures to combat the crime of lynching.

I don't understand the meaning of **to** in the bold part.

Does  it mean **in honour of**

Comment: It looks like a mistake to me. More natural would be *issued a notice . . . **of** a plea.*

Comment: For all I know "issuing a notice to a plea" might be a technical term relating to the procedures of the Supreme Court. It is not uncommon for technical terms to defy the conventional rules of grammar,

Comment: It does look like a mistake, but JeremyC could be right.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't understand the meaning of to in the bold part.**

In fact **to** indicates the relation ship between the notice and the judgement

> **to preposition (CONNECTION)** ​ in connection with [Link to C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to)
>   ​

Example

> What was their response to your query?

What was their response in connection with your query?

Let try some substitutes

Last week the Supreme Court issued a notice to the Centre, the National Human Rights Commission (NHRC) and the State governments, **in connection with a plea**
seeking the implementation of its July 2018 judgment laying down several preventive, remedial and punitive measures to combat the crime of lynching.

Now from this we can see that in this case **to** is an important part of the statement and cannot be removed.